# Can't import maven into Eclipse - maven-compilier-plugin:2.3.2:compile

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-2, m2eclipse

I did see several posts about this issue, but they didn't work for me...
Here is my environment:

Eclipse Juno version: Juno Service Release 1
m2e: 1.4.0
maven: 2.2.1

I generated a HelloWorld sample with Maven and tried to import it into Eclipse by doing File -> Import -> Existing Maven Projects -> Browse -> select Hello World -> Next. However, it shows two errors:

maven-compilier-plugin:2.3.2:compile(1 errors)

maven-compilier-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile(1 errors)

I expended these two and similar notices as follows:

Execution default-compile, in/pom.xml

Execution default-testCompile, in/pom.xml

Comment: Does the maven project build successfully outside Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, it could compile successfully

Comment: Can you show the full error essage? Why are you using an old Maven version and not Maven 3. Furthermore why using an old Eclipse version and not Keppler?

Comment: @khmarbaise The reason I am using Maven 2 is that Maven 3, somehow, doesn't work because of the proxy in my company. Actually, this problem has been resolved but I do have another one, below is the error message: